# $.get Method not work in windows phone 8 phonegap

Tags: cordova

Welcome everybody

I start programming to windows phone 8  using phonegap but the problem the $.get method dose not work when try
my app in windows phone simulator

but when try it in browser works Successfully

so How i can solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
$.get('li.tmpl', function (response) { elementsTmpl = _.template(response);
$.each(titles, function (index, data) { alert(data); addItem(data); });
```

Comment: If you show us your code, we might be able to help you.

Comment: $.get('li.tmpl', function (response) {
                    elementsTmpl = _.template(response);
                    $.each(titles, function (index, data) {
                        alert(data);
                        addItem(data);
                    });

Comment: Update your jQuery, The newest jQuery suppoerts this!

Answer (score 1):

I have already done something similar in reading template using **$.get** successfully in Windows Phone Phonegap application. Here is my suggestion :

You can track what is the culprit of your problem in reading your  element by using this :

```
$.get(your_element).success(function(template, status, response) {
    console.log(response.responseText);
}).error(function(error) {
    console.log("error "+ error.status +": "+ error.statusText);
});
```

If your **$.get** is getting failed, then you will get the error message and start to detect what's wrong there.